# Monaca で画面を横固定にする前に1秒ほど縦表示を挟みたい

Tags: android, monaca

MONACAでアプリを作成中です。

androidで、横表示固定にしたいのですが、その前に一度縦表示を一回挟みたいのです。

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape"/>
```

で横固定にはできるのですが、その前に1秒ほど縦表示を挟むにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

縦横固定を動的に変更するのはユーザの視点が変わるため端末の回転を要求します。
そのためユーザのストレスに繋がるのであまりオススメできませんが
Monacaで行おうと思った場合はCordovaPluginが必要になります。
プラグインを使用するためには使用できるプランに入っている必要があります。

要件を満たしているようなプラグインは下記がありました。
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

```
//縦固定
screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
//横固定
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
//固定開放
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

縦画像のスプラッシュを挟みたいというだけなら、
プラグインを使わずに縦画像を横に90度回転させて登録すればいいと思います。